# Websphere Application Server Patching Backup

Tags: websphere, patch

Hi I wanted to understand the backup process for patching websphere. Should you run configBackup.sh on the app servers themselves as well or just the dmgr server before patching?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere has an Installation Manager to install/roll back fixpack installation, so you dont really need any backup. See details for installing fixpacks here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=product-installing-uninstalling-fix-packs

As you install fixpack on the stopped server, if you want to be extra safe, you can backup WebSphre/AppServer folder.

Running backupConfig.sh doesnt make any sense since installing fixpack is not altering "configuration" only binary files.

The only requirements is that your `dmgr` installation must be on the higher or equal level as your nodes, so you need to start applying fixpacks from dmgr installation.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to make a snapshot of the server and just revert in case of unsolvable issues.
I just patched to a newer minor version, from 9.0.5.14 to 9.0.5.17 and SDK from 8.0.7.20 to 8.0.8.11 and it worked just fine without taking any kind of backup considering the rolback option from the Installation Manager.
It went just fine.